# Relative by blood

Tags: phrases

Does English has a term called **''relative by blood''?**

Let's say you are reminding your relative that:

> ''I ain't just like the others, coz I am your **relative... by blood''**

There's *''blood relative''* term by googling, but I ain't sure if you can break it down, as for the word order I have just done here.

Comment: [**blood relative** is much more common than *relative by blood*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blood+relative%2Cblood+relation%2Crelative+by+blood%2Crelation+by+blood&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblood%20relative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblood%20relation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelative%20by%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelation%20by%20blood%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: One extremely common saying in English that may interest you is ["blood is thicker than water"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_is_thicker_than_water), which means that relationships between **blood relatives** is always more important than any other kind of personal relationship.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: I know that common adage, and thx, but my question is, can I actually say that 'relative by blood'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of being related "by blood" is very common, but as @stangdon points out in the comments, the *exact wording* "relative by blood" is not common.

It's [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blood%20relative%2Cblood%20relation%2Crelative%20by%20blood%2Crelation%20by%20blood%2C%20related%20by%20blood&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblood%20relative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblood%20relation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelative%20by%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelation%20by%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelated%20by%20blood%3B%2Cc0) to say "related by blood".

You example sounds odd to me, since someone using otherwise questionable grammar likely would not say something so out of the ordinary like "relative by blood".

This sounds more natural to me:

> "I ain't just like the others, coz we're related... by blood"

Comment: Nice! I think this is what I should be saying after you have re-word my sentence. Thx very much.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a relative by blood is the opposite of the case, "a relative by marriage".

A brother is a relative by blood; my brother's wife is a "sister-in-law", a relative by marriage.

Comment: Where are you from? Have you heard this specific phrase I'm asking in you country or something you have come across...

Comment: I'm from the United States. "Relative by blood" is not uncommon. I've used it, heard it used, etc. It's more formal, but not awkwardly so. It's the difference between saying, "the mother of my child" and "my kid's mom."

Comment: @JohnA - It's not obscure; you can even find it used [on t-shirts](https://goo.gl/images/CP9HsJ).